# Sqs vs SqsGen2 using RightScale right_aws GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, right-aws, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use the right_aws (1.10.0) GEM with Rails, and I've reduced my problem to a 3-line irb session. The following works

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'right_aws'
sqs = RightAws::Sqs.new("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

while this fails

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'right_aws'
sqs = RightAws::SqsGen2.new("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

with `NameError: uninitialized constant RightAws::SqsGen2`. I see the class definition in the GEM source, the documentation is old but seems accurate, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

And while you're at it, is there any reason if I'm building something new, I'd want to use the older interface?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rails are you using? Maybe try to check latest versions of aws gem(2.4.4)?